# Twilio - ERROR 21211 - Invalid 'To' Phone Number for M2M SIM card

Tags: sms, twilio, iot

Is there a possibility to send SMS to an M2M number (in my case consisting of country code plus 13 digits) using Twilio?

I tried using curl:

```
curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSID}/Messages.json -d "Body=test" -d "To=%2Bxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx" -d "From=%2Bxx xxxxxxxxxxx" -u "{AccountSID}:{authToken}"
```

And the result is

```
{"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number +xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "status": 400}
```

The number is definitely valid, since I can send SMS e.g. from my phone to this number.

When I remove the last three digits of the longer number, I do not get any error.

Comment: Did you try taking the space out of the phone number in your cURL?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does the phone number you are trying to send to conform to the E.164 standard?

Comment: Yes, it does - as far as I know. The first two digits are a valid country code (+46), followed by 13 digits.

Comment: Same issue here, trying a M2M number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the **From/Sender** number before using the API.
Use [this link on Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) to create your **From** Number.

**Remember to use the number on format E.164 standard**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxx/Messages.json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxx==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'Body=lalala' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+1205850xxxx' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+55119756xxxxx'
```